# MS-Access VBA Listbox.ItemData underlying data type

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, type-conversion

Please consider the tiny snippet below:

```
 If rs!Manufacturer = myListbox.ItemData(Index) Then
```

And this two watches:

```
Watch :  rs!Manufacturer.Value            :  1    : Variant/Long
Watch :  Me.myListbox.ItemData(Index)     : "1"   : Variant/String
```

Being `rs!Manufacturer.Value` an integer value from a table `myTable` retrieved by recordset `rs` and `Me.myListbox.ItemData(Index)` the exact same data but shown in a `ListBox` control in my form and retrieved from the very same table.

It seems very clear that listbox is converting the original data type to a string representation of the original value and so, the comparison with the given values fail while I was expecting it to succeed...

**So the question is: is there a (simple) way to retrieve data from my listbox with the original data type (in other words, the same data type as it is in my table)?**

Many can point that I could easily convert the listbox value back to integer with `CInt()` or `CLng()` but it would make my code heavily bound to each specific situation while retrieving data in its original type, no matter which, would make code cleaner and still fully reliable.

Ok, another idea would be converting the recordset value to `string` as well but from a C-programmer perspective it seems too painful to me, so I´d rather avoid it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

*List*- and *ComboBox* always returns a string.

It's really no big deal. You will know the data type of the field of your recordset, so just convert if needed - like:

```
rs!Manufacturer.Value = Val(Me!myListbox.ItemData(Index))
```

**Addendum**

If you wish to carry forward the data type, just do so by adding a column to the listbox you fill with `VarType` of the value when you fill the listbox.

When reading a value from the listbox, also read the (hidden) column holding the data type, and have a function with a `Select .. Case` construct to convert the text value to the original data type.

Comment: Hello Gustav. Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately `Val()` is not what I am looking for neither is it a panacea. `Val()` only serves in conversions from `String` to number and is severely limited on localised numbers. In the end I don´t have the original information, but a parsed one.

Comment: I don't know "what you are looking for". I have programmed in Access since version 1.0 and have never met this as an issue you could not easily work around, so I have the feeling that you are chasing ghosts. `Val` works for any integer/long which was what you mentioned. If you have decimals not having dot as decimal separator, use `CCur` or `CDbl`.